# How to make custom widget in things board?

Tags: widget, thingsboard

Can any one tell me how to create custom widget in things board? I want to create widget for operator position where operator can enter reason why machine is not working? like answers.

Answer (score 3):

A complete overview for creating custom Thingsboard widgets can be found back on the following link (official thingsboard documentation):
[Thingsboard Widget Development](https://thingsboard.io/docs/user-guide/contribution/widgets-development/)

Couple of tips:

- Basic knowledge of web development is definitely usefull (html, css, javascript).
- Basic widget API is important, the subscription object holds your data (see this [link](https://thingsboard.io/docs/user-guide/contribution/widgets-development/)).
- Use (import/edit) the default widgets for code examples, they're a great starting point.

I hope this gets you started.